# Criar novo diretório de acordo com string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, arquivo, upload

Tenho uma função que salva uma imagem em um diretório padrão, para todas as empresas, e tentei alterar isso para salvar em um diretório de acordo com essa string `companyFolder`que criei. Porém assim não está ficando salvo.

Como posso fazer isso?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult StoreImage(int idCompany)
{
    try
    {
        var companyFolder = idCompany.ToString(); 
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(companyFolder)); //creates new directory
        int numFiles = 0; //numero de imagens no diretorio da empresa

        var file = Request.Files["UploadFile"]; //arquivo que foi enviado para upload
        if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0)) //adicionar verificaçao de quantidade de imagens (para limitar a 5)
        {
            string fn = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName); //obtem nome do arquivo
            var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/upload_empresa/" + companyFolder + "/")); //diretorio onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
            //var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/upload_empresa/" + companyFolder));
            FileInfo[] existingImage = dir.GetFiles("imd_" + idCompany + "_*.*");

            string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/upload_empresa/" + companyFolder + "/imd_" + idCompany + "_" + existingImage.Length + Path.GetExtension(fn));

            try
            {
                file.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { success = "false", message = "erro" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: vi agora no console que é gerada a seguinte exceção:

> Exceção gerada: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' em mscorlib.dll

Comment: consegui criar, descobri que ali no System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(companyFolder)); é preciso passar todo o caminho, e não só o nome da pasta a ser criada

Answer (score -1):

Verifique se o diretório que está tentando salvar a imagem existe:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(SaveLocation))
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveLocation)

file.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
```

Comment: não é necessário verificar se existe, se não existir ele cria o diretório